# jQuery - Run function/code if radio button is NOT selected

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to run the code in the IF statement. I only want it to run if the radio button is NOT checked prior to clicking on it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#r2").click(function() {
    if($("#radio_2").not(':checked')) {
      $("#radio_2").prop("checked", true);
      $('#object_type').html("<b>Loading...</b>");
      $.post("sql_s.php",{test: 2,}, function(data){$('#object_type').html(data);});
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#r3").click(function() {
    if($("#radio_3").not(':checked')) {
      $("#radio_3").prop("checked", true);
      $('#object_type').html("<b>Loading...</b>");
      $.post("sql_s.php",{test: 3,}, function(data){$('#object_type').html(data);});
    }
  });
});
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<form action="" id="trans_type">
  <b>Title</b><br />
  <span id="r2"><input type="radio" name="tt1" value="2" id="radio_2" />Option one &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
  <span id="r3"><input type="radio" name="tt1" value="3" id="radio_3" />Option two</span>
  <div id="object_type"></div>
</form>
```

Also any suggestions to combine the two jQuery functions above into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one function that will work for both:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#r2,#r3").click(function () {
        var radio = this.children[0];
        if (!radio.checked) {
            radio.checked = true;
            $('#object_type').html("<b>Loading...</b>");
            var idNumber = this.id.match(/.*(\d+)/)[1];
            $.post("sql_s.php", {
                test: idNumber
            }, function (data) {
                $('#object_type').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
    $("#radio_2,#radio_3").change(function(){
       this.checked = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: This works when I click on the r2 or r3 <div> but not when I click on the radio button itself. It does not load the required data.

Comment: @Sandor You can set the checked state to false in the onchange handler for the radiobuttons and it will work, I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

The [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not) is a filter method which will return a jQuery object which contains elements from original set that does not satisfies the passed selector so it will always be truthy.

You need to use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is) like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#r3").click(function () {
        if (!$("#radio_3").is(':checked')) {
            $("#radio_3").prop("checked", true);
            $('#object_type').html("<b>Loading...</b>");
            $.post("sql_s.php", {
                test: 3,
            }, function (data) {
                $('#object_type').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Another option is

```
if ($("#radio_3").is(':not(:checked)')) {
}
```

Comment: This works when I click on the r3 <div> but not when I click on the radio button itself. It does not load the required data.

Answer (score 0):

The click event for a radio button is only fired after the selection state has been updated, therefore the state of the radio button will always be checked inside your function.  You really just want to respond to clicks on unselected radio buttons, rather than handling all clicks and checking the state.

Use the change event from jquery - this only fires when the value of a control changes.  For a radio button, this will only be called when an unchecked radio button is clicked, as you can not manually unselect a radio button.

Here is a function that will work for your particular example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function rbChange(event) {
        var rb = $(event.currentTarget);
        var val = rb.val();
        // $.post(....)
        $('#result').text(val + ' unchecked.  Loading Data...');
    }
    $('#trans_type').on('change', '[name="tt1"]', rbChange);
});
```